# How to append a character to a string in Swift?

Tags: swift, string

This used to work in Xcode 6: Beta 5. Now I'm getting a compilation error in Beta 6.

```
for aCharacter: Character in aString {
    var str: String = ""
    var newStr: String = str.append(aCharacter) // ERROR
    ...
}
```

**Error**: Cannot invoke `append` with an argument of type `Character`

Comment: Yep. That was the original syntax I used and gave this error: cannot invoke '+' with an argument list of type '(Character, @lvalue String)'

Comment: `append` returns `Void` and only mutates the string.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Update for the moving target that is Swift:

Swift no longer has a + operator that can take a String and an array of characters. (There is a string method `appendContentsOf()` that can be used for this purpose).

The best way of doing this now is Martin R’s answer in a comment below:

```
var newStr:String = str + String(aCharacter)
```

Original answer:
This changed in Beta 6. Check the release notes.I'm still downloading it, but try using:

```
var newStr:String = str + [aCharacter]
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I guess I'm suppose to infer that an array of characters is a string? No mention of this specific syntax in release notes for Beta 6.

Comment: It could have been clearer but it does say "You can still + two Characters or a String with any other sequence of Character or an Array with any other sequence of the same element type." From that, I decided to make the character into an array with the [] syntax.

Comment: `var newStr:String = str + String(aCharacter)` works as well.

Comment: Above answer returns `'String' is not identical to 'Uint8'`. I guess the latest official version is different to the beta used by Gary. So the right answer seems to be that of Martin R.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing to get `'String' is not identical to 'Uint8'` but I agree that Martin's answer will be correct in more circumstances.

Answer (score 11):

This also works

```
var newStr:String = str + String(aCharacter)
```

Comment: ...and I would say is the 'Swifter' way to do it.

Answer (score 9):

append `append(c: Character)` IS the right method but your code has two other problems.

The first is that to iterate over the characters of a string you must access the `String.characters` property.

The second is that the append method doesn't return anything so you should remove the newStr.

The code then looks like this:

```
for aCharacter : Character in aString.characters {
    var str:String = ""
    str.append(aCharacter)
    // ... do other stuff
}
```

Comment: right, just setting up a loop like the OP. Added do other stuff comment

Answer (score 6):

Another possible option is

```
var s: String = ""
var c: Character = "c"
s += "\(c)"
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [Swift 4 Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) ,
You can append a Character value to a String variable with the String type’s append() method:

```
var welcome = "hello there"

let exclamationMark: Character = "!"
welcome.append(exclamationMark)
// welcome now equals "hello there!"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var stringName: String = "samontro"
var characterNameLast: Character = "n"
stringName += String(characterNameLast) // You get your name "samontron"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to get initials from first and last names, and join them together. Using bits and pieces of the above answers, this worked for me:

```
  var initial: String = ""

            if !givenName.isEmpty {
                let char = (givenName as NSString).substring(with: NSMakeRange(0, 1))
               let str = String(char)
                initial.append(str)
            }

            if !familyName.isEmpty {
                 let char = (familyName as NSString).substring(with: NSMakeRange(0, 1))
                let str = String(char)
                initial.append(str)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

for those looking for swift 5, you can do interpolation.

```
var content = "some random string"
content = "\(content)!!"
print(content) // Output: some random string!!
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 let original:String = "Hello"
 var firstCha = original[original.startIndex...original.startIndex]

 var str = "123456789"
 let x = (str as NSString).substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(0, 4))

 var appendString1 = "\(firstCha)\(x)" as String!
 // final name
 var namestr = "yogesh"
 var appendString2 = "\(namestr) (\(appendString1))" as String!*
```