# How to convert Data to hex string in swift

Tags: swift, swift3

I want the hexadecimal representation of a Data value in Swift.

Eventually I'd want to use it like this:

```
let data = Data(base64Encoded: "aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=")!
print(data.hexString)
```

Answer (score 248, accepted):

A simple implementation (taken from [How to hash NSString with SHA1 in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761344/how-to-crypt-string-to-sha1-with-swift/25762128#25762128), with an additional option for uppercase output) would be

```
extension Data {
    struct HexEncodingOptions: OptionSet {
        let rawValue: Int
        static let upperCase = HexEncodingOptions(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    }

    func hexEncodedString(options: HexEncodingOptions = []) -> String {
        let format = options.contains(.upperCase) ? "%02hhX" : "%02hhx"
        return self.map { String(format: format, $0) }.joined()
    }
}
```

I chose a `hexEncodedString(options:)` method  in the style of the existing method `base64EncodedString(options:)`.

`Data` conforms to the `Collection` protocol, therefore one can use
`map()` to map each byte to the corresponding hex string.
The `%02x` format prints the argument in base 16, filled up to two digits
with a leading zero if necessary. The `hh` modifier causes the argument
(which is passed as an integer on the stack) to be treated as a one byte
quantity. One could omit the modifier here because `$0` is an *unsigned*
number (`UInt8`) and no sign-extension will occur, but it does no harm leaving
it in.

The result is then joined to a single string.

Example:

```
let data = Data([0, 1, 127, 128, 255])
// For Swift < 4.2 use:
// let data = Data(bytes: [0, 1, 127, 128, 255])
print(data.hexEncodedString()) // 00017f80ff
print(data.hexEncodedString(options: .upperCase)) // 00017F80FF
```

---

The following implementation is faster by a factor about 50
(tested with 1000 random bytes). It is inspired to
[RenniePet's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42079976/1187415)
and [Nick Moore's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47476781/1187415), but takes advantage of
[`String(unsafeUninitializedCapacity:initializingUTF8With:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3565957-init)
which was introduced with Swift 5.3/Xcode 12 and is available on macOS 11 and iOS 14 or newer.

This method allows to create a Swift string from UTF-8 units efficiently, without unnecessary copying or reallocations.

An alternative implementation for older macOS/iOS versions is also provided.

```
extension Data {
    struct HexEncodingOptions: OptionSet {
        let rawValue: Int
        static let upperCase = HexEncodingOptions(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    }

    func hexEncodedString(options: HexEncodingOptions = []) -> String {
        let hexDigits = options.contains(.upperCase) ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef"
        if #available(macOS 11.0, iOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0, tvOS 14.0, *) {
            let utf8Digits = Array(hexDigits.utf8)
            return String(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: 2 * self.count) { (ptr) -> Int in
                var p = ptr.baseAddress!
                for byte in self {
                    p[0] = utf8Digits[Int(byte / 16)]
                    p[1] = utf8Digits[Int(byte % 16)]
                    p += 2
                }
                return 2 * self.count
            }
        } else {
            let utf16Digits = Array(hexDigits.utf16)
            var chars: [unichar] = []
            chars.reserveCapacity(2 * self.count)
            for byte in self {
                chars.append(utf16Digits[Int(byte / 16)])
                chars.append(utf16Digits[Int(byte % 16)])
            }
            return String(utf16CodeUnits: chars, count: chars.count)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While I typically don't like an `extension` on an Apple class when a `func` can be used I love the symmetry with `base64EncodedString`.

Comment: @reza_khalafi: There are many solutions for Objective-C, for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305225/best-way-to-serialize-an-nsdata-into-a-hexadeximal-string.

Comment: Can you also provide a reverse operation from string to Hex data

Comment: Is this answer works for utf8? Because my server only accepts utf8 characters.

Comment: @MiladFaridnia: I do not understand your question. `Data` contains arbitrary bytes and has no encoding.

Comment: You have mentioned "based on UTF-16 code units" , I want to send this data to server which only accepts utf-8 code units.  I doubt it may not compatible with that server.

Comment: @MiladFaridnia: UTF-16 is what Swift strings use *internally.* The above function returns a string containing only digits 0...9 and the letters A...F, so that should not be a problem.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei: May I ask why you added `self.` at various places in the code? Were there any problems in compiling (or running) the code as it was before?

Comment: @MartinR, I added them to make properties accessing explicit, hence, easier to understand for beginners, which might not know (yet) about the fact that you can omit them and have the same result.

Comment: This does not appear to work for me. I keep getting leading 0 or sublast character as 0 in some cases.
Example:
0x1234 becomes 0x01234,
0x1 becomes 0x01

Comment: @iOSBlacksmith: This code takes a `Data` object (a byte buffer) and produces a hexadecimal string representation. It will always output an even number of characters, two characters (00..FF) per byte. But I don't see how my function could output `0x01234`. Can you give a short self-contained code example?

Answer (score 44):

This code extends the `Data` type with a computed property. It iterates through the bytes of data and concatenates the byte's hex representation to the result:

```
extension Data {
    var hexDescription: String {
        return reduce("") {$0 + String(format: "%02x", $1)}
    }
}
```

Comment: My favorite (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/25762128/1187415): `return map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()`

Comment: "For every byte, there is a string allocation and copy operation being performed." I don't think that's correct. I think Swift does a fairly good job of optimizing String manipulation. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36397955/253938

Comment: I agree with your edit, removing the warning about poor efficiency. So my above comment should be ignored, but I'll leave it there for the sake of posterity.

Comment: I like this approach better as I assume it takes one less pass through the collection.

Answer (score 31):

My version. It's about 10 times faster than the [original] accepted answer by Martin R.

```swift
public extension Data {
    private static let hexAlphabet = Array("0123456789abcdef".unicodeScalars)
    func hexStringEncoded() -> String {
        String(reduce(into: "".unicodeScalars) { result, value in
            result.append(Self.hexAlphabet[Int(value / 0x10)])
            result.append(Self.hexAlphabet[Int(value % 0x10)])
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Was able to make this a tidbit better if you wanna pull my changes into this answer: https://gist.github.com/BenLeggiero/916bf788000736a7c0e6d1cad6e54410

Answer (score 16):

**Swift 4 - From Data to Hex String**
Based upon [Martin R's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40089462/136819) but even a tiny bit faster.

```
extension Data {
  /// A hexadecimal string representation of the bytes.
  func hexEncodedString() -> String {
    let hexDigits = Array("0123456789abcdef".utf16)
    var hexChars = [UTF16.CodeUnit]()
    hexChars.reserveCapacity(count * 2)

    for byte in self {
      let (index1, index2) = Int(byte).quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: 16)
      hexChars.append(hexDigits[index1])
      hexChars.append(hexDigits[index2])
    }

    return String(utf16CodeUnits: hexChars, count: hexChars.count)
  }
}
```

**Swift 4 - From Hex String to Data**
I've also added a fast solution for converting a hex String into Data (based on a [C solution](https://gist.github.com/vi/dd3b5569af8a26b97c8e20ae06e804cb)).

```
extension String {
  /// A data representation of the hexadecimal bytes in this string.
  func hexDecodedData() -> Data {
    // Get the UTF8 characters of this string
    let chars = Array(utf8)

    // Keep the bytes in an UInt8 array and later convert it to Data
    var bytes = [UInt8]()
    bytes.reserveCapacity(count / 2)

    // It is a lot faster to use a lookup map instead of strtoul
    let map: [UInt8] = [
      0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, // 01234567
      0x08, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 89:;<=>?
      0x00, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x00, // @ABCDEFG
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00  // HIJKLMNO
    ]

    // Grab two characters at a time, map them and turn it into a byte
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: count, by: 2) {
      let index1 = Int(chars[i] & 0x1F ^ 0x10)
      let index2 = Int(chars[i + 1] & 0x1F ^ 0x10)
      bytes.append(map[index1] << 4 | map[index2])
    }

    return Data(bytes)
  }
}
```

**Note:** this function does not validate the input. Make sure that it is only used for hexadecimal strings with (an even amount of) characters.

Answer (score 7):

Backward compatible and fast solution:

```swift
extension Data {
    /// Fast convert to hex by reserving memory (instead of mapping and join).
    public func toHex(uppercase: Bool = false) -> String {
        // Constants (Hex has 2 characters for each Byte).
        let size = self.count * 2;
        let degitToCharMap = Array((
            uppercase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef"
        ).utf16);
        // Reserve dynamic memory (plus one for null termination).
        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<unichar>.allocate(capacity: size + 1);
        // Convert each byte.
        var index = 0
        for byte in self {
            buffer[index] = degitToCharMap[Int(byte / 16)];
            index += 1;
            buffer[index] = degitToCharMap[Int(byte % 16)];
            index += 1;
        }
        // Set Null termination.
        buffer[index] = 0;
        // Casts to string (without any copying).
        return String(utf16CodeUnitsNoCopy: buffer,
                      count: size, freeWhenDone: true)
    }
}
```

> **Note** that above passes ownership of `buffer` to returned `String` object.
>
> Also know that, because Swift's internal `String` data is `UTF16` (but can be `UTF8` since Swift 5), all solutions provided in accepted answer do full copy (and are slower), at least if NOT `#available(macOS 11.0, iOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0, tvOS 14.0, *)` ;-)
>
> As mentioned on my profile, usage under `Apache 2.0` license is allowed too (without attribution need).

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't really answer the OP's question since it works on a Swift byte array, not a Data object. And it's much bigger than the other answers. But it should be more efficient since it avoids using String(format: ).

Anyway, in the hopes someone finds this useful ...

```
public class StringMisc {

   // MARK: - Constants

   // This is used by the byteArrayToHexString() method
   private static let CHexLookup : [Character] =
      [ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" ]


   // Mark: - Public methods

   /// Method to convert a byte array into a string containing hex characters, without any
   /// additional formatting.
   public static func byteArrayToHexString(_ byteArray : [UInt8]) -> String {

      var stringToReturn = ""

      for oneByte in byteArray {
         let asInt = Int(oneByte)
         stringToReturn.append(StringMisc.CHexLookup[asInt >> 4])
         stringToReturn.append(StringMisc.CHexLookup[asInt & 0x0f])
      }
      return stringToReturn
   }
}
```

Test case:

```
  // Test the byteArrayToHexString() method
  let byteArray : [UInt8] = [ 0x25, 0x99, 0xf3 ]
  assert(StringMisc.byteArrayToHexString(byteArray) == "2599F3")
```

Comment: Here's a more Swifty version of this answer: https://gist.github.com/BenLeggiero/ce1e62fe0194ca969eb7cdda6639a011

Answer (score 1):

A bit different from other answers here:

```
extension DataProtocol {
    func hexEncodedString(uppercase: Bool = false) -> String {
        return self.map {
            if $0 < 16 {
                return "0" + String($0, radix: 16, uppercase: uppercase)
            } else {
                return String($0, radix: 16, uppercase: uppercase)
            }
        }.joined()
    }
}
```

However in my basic XCTest + measure setup this was fastest of the 4 I tried.

Going through a 1000 bytes of (the same) random data 100 times each:

Above: Time average: 0.028 seconds, relative standard deviation: 1.3%

MartinR: Time average: 0.037 seconds, relative standard deviation: 6.2%

Zyphrax: Time average: 0.032 seconds, relative standard deviation: 2.9%

NickMoore: Time average: 0.039 seconds, relative standard deviation: 2.0%

Repeating the test returned the same relative results. (Nick and Martins sometimes swapped)

Edit:
Nowadays I use this:

```
    var hexEncodedString: String {
        return self.reduce(into:"") { result, byte in
            result.append(String(byte >> 4, radix: 16))
            result.append(String(byte & 0x0f, radix: 16))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Maybe not the fastest, but `data.map({ String($0, radix: 16) }).joined()` does the job.</strike> As mentioned in the comments, this solution was flawed.

Comment: That is problematic because no leading zeros are inserted for single-digit hex numbers. Example: For `Data(bytes: [0x11, 0x02, 0x03, 0x44])` it returns the string "112344" instead of "11020344".