# Different console output data via NSData and Data (Xcode 8 beta 6, Swift 3)

Tags: swift, xcode, nsdata, swift3

I write a little snippet of usual code but found that my code don't return hex data from server with this line of code:

```
let currentData = try! Data(contentsOf: fullURL!)
print("currentData=", currentData)
```

And the output:

```
currentData= 24419 bytes
```

I tried to use Leo's comment link:

stackoverflow.com/q/39075043/2303865

I got something hex data without spaces, and validator (http://jsonprettyprint.com) can't recognise it and returns null.

Comment: You were probably (ab)using the fact that the description method of NSData returns a "hex dump", which is no longer true for Data. But the data is there. Why do you think it isn't, and what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @MartinR I just want to get data and then use JSONSerialization to get it into JSON format.

Comment: And `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: currentData)` does not work? What result do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: Serialisation is ok. But want to see output and try to print currentData (with Data()) but console shows kind of garbage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39075043/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus: This looks more like an XY-problem to me. If OP wants to deserialize JSON data then the hex dump is irrelevant.

Comment: So all he needs is to convert the data to String utf8

Comment: @wm.p1us: Your update does not help. There is no `print` statement in your code, therefore we cannot answer why you don't see any print data in the console.

Comment: @wm.p1us: Can you remove the unrelated stuff? Have you checked if the link that Leo pointed to answers your question? What does `print("currentData=", currentData)` show?

Comment: Can you post your actual code? As Martin already mentioned you need to use JSONObjectWithData to serialize your data

Comment: I can serialise it so I got correct JSON. But I want to understand why hex data which I can get with your link returns nil in jsonprettyprint.com

Comment: You can print the returned data using `String(data: currentData, encoding: .utf8)`

Comment: Your first link make hex data in the console appear. So I think that was correct way to do things. But now I try to figure out why that hex data I can't convert  to normal JSON format with online services.

Comment: @LeoDabus I know this is just test new classes code. It's unsafe.

Comment: @wm.p1us: http://jsonprettyprint.com requires the JSON as a string, not as hex data. It wouldn't work with the hex output from NSData either.

Comment: Omg I understand it at the same time you wrote. Have to sleep :( Please wrote some answer about console output and I accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try to sort out the different issues here and summarize the
above comments.

The `description` method
of `Data` prints only a short summary "NNN bytes", and not a hex dump
as `NSData` did:

```
let o = ["foo": "bar"]
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: o)

print(jsonData) // 13 bytes
```

You can get a hex dump by bridging to `NSData` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift#comment65529962_39075044)):

```
print(jsonData as NSData) // <7b22666f 6f223a22 62617222 7d>
```

or by writing an extension method for `Data` ([How to convert Data to hex string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift)).

But that is actually not the real problem. The JSON validator needs
the JSON as a *string,* not as a hex dump ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39178140/different-console-output-data-via-nsdata-and-data-xcode-8-beta-6-swift-3#comment65698998_39178140)):

```
print(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!) // {"foo":"bar"}
```

And to de-serialize the JSON data into an object you would need
none of the above and just call

```
let obj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData)
```