# Convert hex-encoded String to String

Tags: swift, character-encoding, swift3

I want to convert following hex-encoded `String` in Swift 3:

```
dcb04a9e103a5cd8b53763051cef09bc66abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffc2a07a4
```

to its equivalant `String`:

```
Ü°J:\Øµ7cï  ¼f«à)ýë®^A~/ü*¤
```

Following websites do the job very fine:

http://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter

http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx

But I am unable to do the same in Swift 3. Following code doesn't do the job too:

```
func convertHexStringToNormalString(hexString:String)->String!{
  if let data = hexString.data(using: .utf8){
      return String.init(data:data, encoding: .utf8)
  }else{ return nil}
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40278391/1187415 for a method  to create `Data` from a hex-encoded string.

Comment: But your data does not look like a valid string in any known encoding ...

Comment: Transform as suggested by Marin R, the Hex Representation that is a String, into its equivalent in `(NS)Data`. And use `NSASCIIStringEncoding`, not `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. I get in Objective-C the correct result `Ü°J:\Øµ7cï ¼f«à)ýë®^A~/ü*¤` with the ASCII, but null with the UTF8.

Comment: Why do you want to store that binary data as a string at all?

Comment: @Larme: That works, but NSASCIIStringEncoding is *documented* as a "strict 7-bit encoding", so one might not rely on it.

Comment: @MartinR True, but if the hex is a representation of the ASCII conversion one, it should work. It's up to the dev to use the correct and most suitable encoding for its own use.

Comment: I believe the "correct" (it's whacky, but seems to be what is desired) encoding here is `.isoLatin1` rather than `.ascii`.

Comment: Thanks @Larme and @MartinR for guiding me to right direction. I converted the hex-String to Data by Martiin's way and converted the Data to  String and thanks it's not nil this time but got this result in swift: `Optional("Ü°J\u{10}:\\Øµ7c\u{05}\u{1C}ï\t¼f«à)ýë®^\u{1D}A~/ü*\u{07}¤")`

Comment: @MartinR, Why am I converting it to String? It is because my php developer want me to send param values encrypted with AES. And the AES key he has provided me is hex-encoded. For me to use [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift), I need to de-code this hex key first... :/

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, you can pass the AES key as a binary blob as well: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift#aes-advanced-usage. – And if you pass it as a string then the string will be converted to its UTF-8 representation, not ISO Latin 1.

Comment: @MartinR, you are right there are two ways. To make binary blob, what should I do? I think use your method to create Data first then merely convert it to `[uInt8]` by `let binaryArray = [UInt8](data)`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the hex encoded data as an AES key, but the
data is not a valid UTF-8 sequence. You *could* interpret
it as a string in ISO Latin encoding, but the `AES(key: String, ...)`
initializer converts the string back to its UTF-8 representation,
i.e. you'll get different key data from what you started with.

Therefore you should not convert it to a string at all. Use the

```
extension Data {
    init?(fromHexEncodedString string: String)
}
```

method from [hex/binary string conversion in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276322/hex-binary-string-conversion-in-swift/40278391#40278391)
to convert the hex encoded string to `Data` and then pass that
as an array to the `AES(key: Array<UInt8>, ...)` initializer:

```
let hexkey = "dcb04a9e103a5cd8b53763051cef09bc66abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffc2a07a4"
let key = Array(Data(fromHexEncodedString: hexkey)!)

let encrypted = try AES(key: key, ....)
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, you have been a lot of help. Can I mark both of the answers as correct?

Comment: @ChanchalRaj - I actually think you should accept this answer because this gets to the heart of your question, namely that you should not be building `String` object at all, but rather use this `[UInt8]` rendition of the AES methods.

Answer (score 7):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does. This line:

if let data = hexString.data(using: .utf8){

means "encode these characters into UTF-8." That means that "01" doesn't encode to 0x01 (1), it encodes to 0x30 0x31 ("0" "1"). There's no "hex" in there anywhere.

This line:

```
  return String.init(data:data, encoding: .utf8)
```

just takes the encoded UTF-8 data, interprets it as UTF-8, and returns it. These two methods are symmetrical, so you should expect this whole function to return whatever it was handed.

Pulling together Martin and Larme's comments into one place here. This appears to be encoded in Latin-1. (This is a really awkward way to encode this data, but if it's what you're looking for, I think that's the encoding.)

```
import Foundation

extension Data {

    // From http://stackoverflow.com/a/40278391:
    init?(fromHexEncodedString string: String) {

        // Convert 0 ... 9, a ... f, A ...F to their decimal value,
        // return nil for all other input characters
        func decodeNibble(u: UInt16) -> UInt8? {
            switch(u) {
            case 0x30 ... 0x39:
                return UInt8(u - 0x30)
            case 0x41 ... 0x46:
                return UInt8(u - 0x41 + 10)
            case 0x61 ... 0x66:
                return UInt8(u - 0x61 + 10)
            default:
                return nil
            }
        }

        self.init(capacity: string.utf16.count/2)
        var even = true
        var byte: UInt8 = 0
        for c in string.utf16 {
            guard let val = decodeNibble(u: c) else { return nil }
            if even {
                byte = val << 4
            } else {
                byte += val
                self.append(byte)
            }
            even = !even
        }
        guard even else { return nil }
    }
}

let d = Data(fromHexEncodedString: "dcb04a9e103a5cd8b53763051cef09bc66abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffc2a07a4")!
let s = String(data: d, encoding: .isoLatin1)
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, for the input. I am wondering why Swift prints the converted string as:
`Optional("Ü°J\u{10}:\\Øµ7c\u{05}\u{1C}ï\t¼f«à)ýë®^\u{1D}A~/ü*\u{07}¤")`
instead of desired: `Ü°J:\Øµ7cï  ¼f«à)ýë®^A~/ü*¤`

Comment: @ChanchalRaj: Because you did not unwrap the optional. *Optional* strings use a slightly different printing method which escapes control characters.

Answer (score 3):

There is still a way to convert the key from hex to readable string by adding the below extension:

```
extension String {
    
    func hexToString()->String{
        
        var finalString = ""
        let chars = Array(self)
        
        for count in stride(from: 0, to: chars.count - 1, by: 2){
            let firstDigit =  Int.init("\(chars[count])", radix: 16) ?? 0
            let lastDigit = Int.init("\(chars[count + 1])", radix: 16) ?? 0
            let decimal = firstDigit * 16 + lastDigit
            let decimalString = String(format: "%c", decimal) as String
            finalString.append(Character.init(decimalString))
        }
        return finalString
        
    }
    
    func base64Decoded() -> String? {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) else { return nil }
        return String(data: data, encoding: .init(rawValue: 0))
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
    let hexToString = secretKey.hexToString()
    let base64ReadableKey = hexToString.base64Decoded() ?? ""
```