# Base64 decode encrypted content in Swift 3

Tags: swift, base64, aes

I'm working on a Swift Framework, connected to my servers. Data are encrypted between the application and the PHP server in AES-256-CBC. I succeed to send data from applications to the server and get the response. But now I'd like to decrypt the response and I can't.

To decrypt the server response I use a vector (sent by the server in Base64), the source data and a key (generated application-side). When I do a base64Decode on my vector, base64 returns nil. It returns nil because my vector contains some special characters and Strings don't handle special char. The problem is, I need a string and my vector to do an AES Decrypt and get back my data.

This is my Swift 3 code :

```
let data = Data(base64Encoded: data)!
let decrypted = try! AES(key: key, iv: iv.base64Decoded()!, blockMode: .CBC, padding: PKCS7()).decrypt([UInt8](data))
let decryptedData = Data(decrypted)
```

And on the second line I get the following error:

`Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

---

**EDIT :**

Precisely, this is what happened :

First I created, server-side, a random vector in PHP :

`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length("AES-256-CBC"));`

... and encode it in base64 because it's composed with special characters.

Now, application-side I try to decode it :

```
extension String {
    func base64Decoded() -> String? {
        if let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) {
            return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        }
        return nil
    }
}


let myVector = iv.base64Decoded()!
```

But that fail, because the decoded string contain non handled characters.
How can I handle them ?

Thanks for all your ideas

Comment: What exactly does `data` contain? Show the output of `print(data as NSData)`.

Comment: `data` contain the result of AES-256-CBC of a JSON.

Comment: Actually it works but only when I use a vector without special characters. But I'd like to deal with special characters...

Comment: What does `iv` contain?

Comment: It contain a random initialization vector, encoded in base 64

Comment: So which part exactly returns nil? – A self-contained example with input, actual results, and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: It's the base64 decode on the IV who returns nil :
`let decodedIV = iv.base64Decoded()!` ->  `Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: That should happen only if `iv` is not valid Base64. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Here is a very similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485494/convert-hex-encoded-string-to-string-in-swift-3, and the solution should be the same: *Don't* try to convert the binary data to a string, but pass it as an array to `AES(key: Array<UInt8>, iv: Array<UInt8>, ..)`

Comment: Thanks, that help me ! Put your comment in answer and I'll validate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot* interpret arbitrary data as an UTF-8 encoded string, therefore
`String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` will fail in most cases.

But there is another `AES` initializer which takes *binary data* (as an array) instead of strings, making the conversion to strings obsolete:

```
let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64data)!
let iv = Data(base64Encoded: base64iv)!

let decrypted = try! AES(Array(data), Array(iv), ...)
```