# Conversion not happening from [UInt] array to Data

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of `UInt`s containing 16 elements and I need to convert it to a `Data` object of 16 bytes.

I am using the below code to convert, but it is converting it to 128 bytes instead of 16 bytes.

```
let numbers : stride(from: 0, to: salt.length, by: 2).map() {
        strtoul(String(chars[$0 ..< min($0 + 2, chars.count)]), nil, 16)
    }
/*numbers is a [UInt] array*/

let data = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: numbers, count:number.count))
/*Data returns 128 bytes instead of 16 bytes*/
```

Please correct me as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: NO. Actually it was 16 * 8 = 128 bytes. It occupies 8 bytes for each int value.

Comment: It seems that what you *actually* want is to convert a hex-encoded string to a `Data` value. Have a look at (for example) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276322/hex-binary-string-conversion-in-swift for  possible solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't convert 16 `UInt`s to 16 bytes. A `UInt` is 8 bytes long on a 64 bit device, or 4 bytes on a 32 bit device. You need to use an array of `UInt8`s.

If you have an array of `UInt`s as input you can't cast them to `UInt8`, but you can convert them:

```
let array: [UInt] = [1, 2, 3, 123, 255]

let array8Bit: [UInt8] = array.map{UInt8($0)}
```

Comment: Afer viewing your code it would be better if you remappped your code to build an array of `UInt8`'s directly.

Comment: Note that if your goal is to convert a hex string to data, the code linked in Martin's comment is really the better solution. @MartinR, you should post that code as an answer, and the OP should accept that, not mine. This question is really an XY problem.