# Swift Hex string Decoding

Tags: swift

I'm going insane trying to get this to work

Trying to duplicate the following java function

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#decodeHex-java.lang.String-

Here is the code from Java

```
public static byte[] decodeHex(final String data) throws DecoderException {
    return decodeHex(data.toCharArray());
}
```

---

```
public static byte[] decodeHex(final char[] data) throws DecoderException {
    final int len = data.length;
    if ((len & 0x01) != 0) {
        throw new DecoderException("Odd number of characters.");
    }
    final byte[] out = new byte[len >> 1];
    // two characters form the hex value.
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < len; i++) {
        int f = toDigit(data[j], j) << 4;
        j++;
        f = f | toDigit(data[j], j);
        j++;
        out[i] = (byte) (f & 0xFF);
    }
    return out;
}
```

---

```
protected static int toDigit(final char ch, final int index) throws DecoderException {
    final int digit = Character.digit(ch, 16);
    if (digit == -1) {
        throw new DecoderException("Illegal hexadecimal character " + ch + " at index " + index);
    }
    return digit;
}
```

---

given the following string `01e703000000000000`
the byte array should contain

```
[1, -25, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

[image]

I thought this may be standard hex decoding so I used the usual decoding function I've been using

```
extension String {
    /// A data representation of the hexadecimal bytes in this string.
    var hexDecodedData: Data {
        // Get the UTF8 characters of this string
        let chars = Array(utf8)
        // Keep the bytes in an UInt8 array and later convert it to Data
        var bytes = [UInt8]()
        bytes.reserveCapacity(count / 2)
        // It is a lot faster to use a lookup map instead of stratal 
        let map: [UInt8] = [
            0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, // 01234567
            0x08, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 89:;<=>?
            0x00, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x00, // @ABCDEFG
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00  // HIJKLMNO
        ]
        // Grab two characters at a time, map them and turn it into a byte
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: count, by: 2) {
            let index1 = Int(chars[i] & 0x1F ^ 0x10)
            let index2 = Int(chars[i + 1] & 0x1F ^ 0x10)
            bytes.append(map[index1] << 4 | map[index2])
        }
        return Data(bytes)
    }
}
```

This results in

[1, 231, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

So the I tried converting the java code to swift myself

```
extension String {
    // public static byte[] decodeHex(final char[] data) throws DecoderException
    func decodeHex() throws -> [Int] {
        let stringArray = Array(self)
        let len = count
        var out: [Int?] = Array(repeating: nil, count: len >> 1)
        if (len & 0x01) != 0 {
            throw HExDecodingError.oddNumberOfCharacters
        }
        var i = 0
        var j = 0
        while j < len {
            var f: Int = try Self.toDigit(char: String(stringArray[j]), index: j)
            j += 1
            f = f | (try Self.toDigit(char: String(stringArray[j]), index: j))
            j += 1
            out[i] = f & 0xFF
            i += 1
        }
        return out.compactMap { $0 }
    }
    enum HExDecodingError: Error {
        case oddNumberOfCharacters
        case illegalCharacter(String)
        case conversionToDogotFailed(String, Int)
    }
    static func toDigit(char: String, index: Int) throws -> Int {
        let digit = Int(char, radix: 16)
        if digit == -1 {
            throw HExDecodingError.illegalCharacter(char)
        }
        guard let  digit = digit else {
            throw HExDecodingError.conversionToDogotFailed(char, index)
        }
        return digit
    }
}
```

Which results in

```
[1, 15, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

What is going on? what am I doing wrong

**EDIT**:
Also how can there possibly be a negative number in there since a byte array is represented as a `[UInt8]`

Comment: The result of your first code attempt looks correct: Java doesn’t have unsigned integers, but Swift does. Signed byte `-25` (Java `byte`, Swift `Int8`) has the same bit pattern as unsigned byte `231` (Swift `UInt8`). Are you looking for a different result? (If you need to match Java results _exactly_, then you should be using `Int8` instead of `UInt8`)

Comment: In your own translation of the Java function, it is incorrect to translate Java's `byte` to `Int`. Java's `byte` is signed and so should be represented as `Int8` in Swift. That should answer the question of "Also how can there possibly be a negative number in there since a byte array is represented as a `[UInt8]`".

Comment: @ItaiFerber is correct thank you, issue is resolved. Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll accept. Yes the code is posted on SO, I was looking for explanation of why bytes appeared different in Java vs Swift as I'm writing tests to match existing Java unit tests

Comment: @aryaxt updated the duplicated post to throw errors as well [How to convert hexadecimal string to an array of UInt8 bytes in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43360864/2303865)

Comment: @aryaxt note that checking if `digit == -1` doesn't make any sense. Int radix is a fallible initializer `init?<S>(_ text: S, radix: Int = 10) where S : StringProtocol`. It will fail instead of return `-1` in other words it would return `nil`

Comment: Note also that String Character type has an `hexDigitValue` instance property which returns an optional Int `let digit = char.hexDigitValue`

Comment: yeah I blindly copied it from java just to see the result, ended up keeping the initial implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Java `byte` primitive type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

(Java, in general, does not have unsigned primitive types, only signed ones.)

In your Java output, the `-25` value corresponds to hex `E7` in your string, whose decimal value is `E * 16 + 7 = 14 * 16 + 7 = 231`; `231` is outside of the `[-128, 127]` range, and wraps around to `-25`. (More precisely the bit pattern of unsigned 8-bit `231` corresponds to the bit pattern of signed 8-bit `-25` in two's-complement.)

In Swift, you're using a `UInt8` to represent results (both explicitly, and implicitly in a `Data` value), and the range of `UInt8` is `[0, 255]`; `231` fits within this range, and is what you see in your first Swift code snippet. The results are bitwise equivalent, but if you need results which are *type* equivalent to what you're seeing in Java, you'll need to work in terms of `Int8` instead of `UInt8`.