# How to send a byte array to ble in Swift 3?

Tags: swift

I am trying to send data to a ble, but my device only accepts byte arrays. How do I convert data to byte array and send it in Swift 3?

```
print("hex value is",hexRepresentation)
print("pairing code",pairingcode)
var aaa = calcchecksum(data:"4A6BF961585C3F86DCEB562CEC51A4CE")

if let auxData = (hexRepresentation+"4A6BF961585C3F86DCEB562CEC51A4CE"+aaa).data(using: .utf8), let lChar = self.mainCharacteristic {   
    let bytearraydata = [UInt8](auxData) as Data?

    aPeripheral.writeValue(bytearraydata, for: lChar, type: .withResponse
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40278391/1187415.

Answer (score 1):

Find to which CBCharacteristic property is write.

```
  let data:[UInt8] = [0x01, 0x03, 0x012, 0x01]
  let writeData =  Data(bytes: data)

  self.selectPeripheral.writeValue(writeData, for: writeCharacteristic, 
  type: WithResponse)
```