# Why Data and NSData print differently

Tags: swift, nsdata

This will, I'm sure, point out my knowledge gap.  But I don't seen anything about this in the S.O. knowledge banks and looking at the foundation code has not shed any light for me.

Basic question: why does Swift's Data print differently than NSData?

e.g.

```
func getData(_ data:Data) {
    print("The TLV was: \(data as NSData)")
}
```

prints:

```
The TLV was: <020101>
```

But ...

```
func getData(_ data:Data) {
    print("The TLV was: \(data)")
}
```

prints:

```
The TLV was: 3 bytes
```

Thanks.

Comment: Because it's rarely useful to print out the full output of a data object containing more than a few bytes.

Comment: Hrmm rmaddy appears to be correct!  The practical seems to outweigh the habitual.  Drat.
Here's a link I found while searching for something else that supports rmaddy and answers the original question inadvertently.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276322/hex-binary-string-conversion-in-swift/40278391#40278391
Thanks rmaddy

Comment: One option to see the bytes of a `Data` instance would be use `dump(data)` (although this prints out the bytes in decimal, not hex). Just bridging to `NSData` is a nice and easy way of seeing them in hex.

Comment: Thanks Hamish:
to give an example:

The TLV was: 3 bytes
▿ 3 bytes
  - count: 3
  ▿ pointer: 0x00000001c00117f0
    - pointerValue: 7516264432
  ▿ bytes: 3 elements
    - 2
    - 1
    - 1

Comment: (although note that `Data`'s dump output only includes the byte values if there are less than 64 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

"Data from Swift 3 has no "built-in" method to print its contents as a hex string, or to create a Data value from a hex string."

rmaddy was right.

Also see:

[hex/binary string conversion in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276322/hex-binary-string-conversion-in-swift/40278391#40278391)