# Difference between writeValue data as NSData in Objective C and Data in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm writing to a CoreBluetooth device using

```
- (void)writeValue:(NSData *)data forCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic type:(CBCharacteristicWriteType)type;
```

in objective C

I would like to move this code over to Swift. Therefore I'm writing using

```
 open func writeValue(_ data: Data, for characteristic: CBCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType)
```

All of the parameter values being sent are the same except data when sent as `NSData` will be represented as such **<000a0302>**. In Swift the data is represented as

> ▿ 4 bytes
>     - count : 4   ▿ pointer : 0x00000002810ce5b0
>       - pointerValue : 10755040688   ▿ bytes : 4 elements
>       - 0 : 0
>       - 1 : 10
>       - 2 : 3
>
> - 3 : 2

However I am not getting the same result back from the bluetooth peripheral - what is the difference between the two examples?

Comment: Possibly helpful: [How to convert Data to hex string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39075043/1187415)

Comment: See also: [Why Data and NSData print differently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44830747/1187415)

Answer (score 4):

Practically there is no difference. `Data` is implicitly bridged to `NSData` and vice versa if necessary.

The difference is how `NSData` and `Data` are displayed to the console.

- `NSData` is represented by the hex bytes in angle brackets (`<000a0302>`).
- `Data` is represented by the number of bytes (`4 bytes`). If you want the `NSData` representation add `as NSData` in the `print` expression

Comment: I'll had that to debug, I use `print(\(data as NSData))` to force the `description` of `NSData` which might be more useful (except, it's a large data).

Comment: po data as NSData shows
<000a0302> - the issue may be that the peripheral is expecting hex

Answer (score 0):

They are exactly the same - I had some nasty wrapper code causing a bug which is now squashed!