# Converting hex to ByteString in Swift

Tags: swift, sha256, hmac

We are trying to connect to [Periodic's API](http://periodic.is/api) using Swift 5. In order to do that, part of the process is encoding a concatenated string in HMAC SHA-256. In our code, we accomplish this by the following code:

```
let hmac = premac.digest(.sha256, key: "API KEY")
```

Which is using the [SwiftCrypto](https://github.com/jernejstrasner/SwiftCrypto) library to accomplish this. According to Periodic's CTO, we are getting close but the issue is that this function's output is giving us a HEX version when we really need the bytestring level.

We are unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276322/hex-binary-string-conversion-in-swift