# Convert Data to String in Swift 3

Tags: string, type-conversion, swift3

I am very new to Swift.

I want to create something like API on Swift for my educational app.

I have this code:

```
static func getFilm(filmID: Int) -> String {
    
    print("getFilm")
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.kinopoisk.cf/getFilm?filmID=\(filmID)")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    var returnData: String = ""
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if var responseVar = response, var dataVar = data {
            print(responseVar)
            returnData = String(data: dataVar, encoding: .utf8)
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    task.resume()
    
    return returnData
}
```

And I try to convert Data to String in this line: `returnData = String(data: dataVar, encoding: .utf8)`

Swift compiler gives me an error, and change this line to
`returnData = String(data: dataVar, encoding: .utf8)!`
, when I execute this line I get empty returnData variable.

If I use basic example line
`print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))`
everything will be OK and I can see `data` in XCode console.

So, how I can convert Data to String?

Comment: The main problem is that you cannot return something from a asynchronous function. You need a completion handler.

Comment: @vadian Please, can you convert my code to code completion handler? I read a lot about them and I don't understand what I need to separate in my code.

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is an example using a completion handler:

```
class func getFilm(filmID: Int, completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.kinopoisk.cf/getFilm?filmID=\(filmID)")!
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url) { (data, response, error) in
      if error != nil {
        print(error!)
        completion("")
      } else {
        if let returnData = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
          completion(returnData)
        } else {
          completion("")
        }
      }
    }.resume()
}
```

And you call it

```
MyClass.getFilm(filmID:12345) { result in
   print(result)
}
```

In case of an error the completion handler returns an empty string.

`MyClass` is the enclosing class of `getFilm` method. Most likely the web service will return JSON, so you might need to deserialize the JSON to an array or dictionary.

---

In a more sophisticated version create an enum with two cases and associated values

```
enum ConnectionResult {
  case success(String), failure(Error)
}
```

With a little more effort demonstrating the subtle power of Swift you can return either the converted string on success of the error on failure in a single object.

```
class func getFilm(filmID: Int, completion: @escaping (ConnectionResult) -> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.kinopoisk.cf/getFilm?filmID=\(filmID)")!
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url) { (data, response, error) in
      if error != nil {
        completion(.failure(error!))
      } else {
        if let returnData = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
          completion(.success(returnData))
        } else {
          completion(.failure(NSError(domain: "myDomain", code: 9999, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "The data is not converible to 'String'"])))
        }
      }
    }.resume()
}
```

On the caller side a `switch` statement separates the cases.

```
MyClass.getFilm(filmID:12345) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let string) : print(string)
    case .failure(let error) : print(error)
    }
}
```

Meanwhile – with `async/await` in Swift 5.5+ – it has become much more comfortable

```
class func getFilm(filmID: Int) async throws -> String {
    print("getFilm")
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.kinopoisk.cf/getFilm?filmID=\(filmID)")!
    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
    return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, but I dont understand, how I can get return value from getFilm? I mean something like this `var test = getFilm()`

Comment: Your `MyClass.getFilm(filmID:12345) { result in
   print(result)
}` just blow my mind. I think it would be simple - I have function with input and output parameters, and I understand how I can get `result` in outer code.

Comment: I think, what's really confusing is that how `result in
   print(result)` gets injected into `completion(returnData)`. I wished there was a bit more elaboration how this magic happens.

Comment: @Houman `result` is a short form for `(result : Result) -> ()`. The `completion` call passes the closure with the appropriate `Result` parameter

Comment: Many errors. Can't implement as a class. If I do so: Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'.

Comment: @Oleksandr The code is supposed to be executed within a class `MyClass`. It works also as an instance method in a view controller without the `class` keyword.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, you can't use `encoding: .utf8` for unpredictable data. It will return `nil` every time.

Use this instead:

`String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)`

Comment: What does it return if data is unpredictable?

Comment: Only thing that worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming in future (which are probably not interested in OP's film code?!);

Simply, try something like:

```swift
extension Data {
    public func toString() -> String {
        return String(data: self, encoding: .utf8) ?? "";
    }
}
```

> ##### See also my [`toHex` related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69477135/8740349)

Answer (score 0):

If you know an instance of Data contains a String and you want to convert it, you should use the String(decoding:as:) initializer, like this:

**let str = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)**

If the Data instance can’t be converted to a UTF-8 string, you’ll get sent back an empty string. This means you do need to know which format is used to store the string, but UTF-8 is usually the best to go with.