# Can't convert encrypted data to String

Tags: swift, encryption

I am trying to learn to use RNCryptor. Here is what I am using:

```
let key = "1234"
let original_text = "hello"
let data = original_text.data(using: .utf8)!
let encrypted_data = RNCryptor.encrypt(data: data, withPassword: key)

print(String(data: encrypted_data, encoding: .utf8))
```

This prints 'nil'. How can I convert `encrypted_data` to a String?

Also, this *does* work:

```
try! print(String(data: RNCryptor.decrypt(data: encrypted_data, withPassword: key), encoding: .utf8))
```

but this is the original text and not the cipher text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The encrypted data is a binary blob, and in most cases *not* a valid
UTF-8 sequence. Therefore the conversion to a string

```
String(data: encrypted_data, encoding: .utf8)
```

fails and returns `nil`. If you want a string representation of the
encrypted data then you can use (for example) the Base64 encoding:

```
print(encrypted_data.base64EncodedString())
```

or, using

```
extension Data {
    func hexEncodedString() -> String {
        return map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
    }
}
```

from [How to convert Data to hex string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift/40089462#40089462), as a hex-encoded string:

```
print(encrypted_data.hexEncodedString())
```

Comment: if I want to share encrypted string to the backend the base64 will not work. Solution??