# Convert CBCharacteristic value to string

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I have app what working with BLE device. I have characteristic value, but I can't convert it to string.
For example,

```
value = <aa640400 0000001e 0f>
```

How convert it to string?

Answer (score 1):

```
let dd = getCharacteristic.value!;

print(String(data: dd, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)!);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation with your code. Code dumps are often downvoted and may even be removed.

Comment: let value = [UInt8](characteristic.value!)

Answer (score 0):

I was using the answer from sandy above and condensed it to

```
let data = (characteristic.value)!    
let nsdataStr = NSData.init(data: (characteristic.value)!)
print("Raw: \(nsdataStr)")
```

All I wanted to do was to get the raw value (in hex) from the BLE peripheral (HR monitor in this case).
The output of the above gives me:

```
// This is the Decimal HRArray:[22, 64, 90, 3] 
Raw: {length = 4, bytes = 0x16404e03}
```

This code below basically just removes the white space

```
let str = nsdataStr.description.trimmingCharacters(in:charSet).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
```

making it

```
Raw: {length=4, bytes=0x16404e03}
```

which I didn't need.

Comment: Please use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift instead. Else, this will be obsolete in future version (iOS13 changed the Data description: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57839723/does-ios-13-has-new-way-of-getting-device-notification-token).

Answer (score -1):

**Follow below code:**

```
let data = (characteristic?.value)!

print(data) //-> It will be of type Data we need to convert Data to String

let charSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>")

let nsdataStr = NSData.init(data: (characteristic?.value)!)

let str = nsdataStr.description.trimmingCharacters(in:charSet).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

print(str) // you will get String or Hex value (if its Hex need one more conversion)
```