# How to convert Data with 32 bytes to string with 32 char length in iOS Swift 3.1?

Tags: ios, swift, base64, decode, encode

I have String with 44 char length and i want to convert it to 32 char length in iOS Swift 3.1

```
let keyString = "u6KuXJLIUwEUl7noY8J8H1ffDRwLC/5gjaWW1qTQ3hE="
```

i use this code for convert it to Data with 32 bytes :

```
let keyData = Data(base64Encoded: keyString)
```

and now , how to convert it to string with 32 char length?

Comment: What should that string be if the bytes are (for example) `<00010203 00000000 ... FFFEFDFC>` ? Interpreting a binary blob as a string (usually) makes no sense. Why do you think that a 32 character string is needed?

Comment: For using in laravel encryption via swift code @MartinR

Comment: Again: How should `<00010203 00000000 ... FFFEFDFC>` be represented as a 32 character string? Or in your concrete case `<bba2ae5c 92c85301 1497b9e8 63c27c1f 57df0d1c 0b0bfe60 8da596d6 a4d0de11>` ?

Comment: just see this in php   $key = "u6KuXJLIUwEUl7noY8J8H1ffDRwLC/5gjaWW1qTQ3hE=";

$key = (string)base64_decode($key);  @MartinR

Comment: What you want seems to be "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift". A representation of the Data into HexString.

Comment: @Larme: That would give 64 characters for 32 bytes :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String(data: keyData, encoding: .utf8)
```

gives you an optional string. Since you know the source data does in fact contain UTF-8/ASCII data, you can safely unwrap it.

Comment: Base64 decoding the string `"u6KuXJLIUwEUl7noY8J8H1ffDRwLC/5gjaWW1qTQ3hE="` from the question gives `<bba2ae5c 92c85301 1497b9e8 63c27c1f 57df0d1c 0b0bfe60 8da596d6 a4d0de11>` which is *not* valid UTF-8.