# iOS Swift 3 BLE read characteristic returning "1 bytes"?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am having problems reading a value from a BLE characteristic after converting to Swift 3.

Before, using `characteristic.value?.description` with Swift 2.x, the value would return a String in hex format, ex: `"<01>"`.

Now with Swift 3, the same code simple returns `"1 bytes"`.

I have dug through SO for similar questions and answers but none speak of `Data` however it seems that it's not returning such an object.

Any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift for various methods to get the contents of a `Data` value as a hex-encoded string.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR!