# Cannot Initialise Variable for type Unsafepointer Swift 3.0 conversion

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am converting existing swift 2.0 code to swift 3.0 but came across an error  while conversion:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeRawPointer)'

Here is my code:

```
extension Data {

  var hexString : String {
    let buf = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(bytes) // here is the error
    let charA = UInt8(UnicodeScalar("a").value)
    let char0 = UInt8(UnicodeScalar("0").value)

    func itoh(_ i: UInt8) -> UInt8 {
        return (i > 9) ? (charA + i - 10) : (char0 + i)
    }

    let p = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: count * 2)

    for i in 0..<count {
        p[i*2] = itoh((buf[i] >> 4) & 0xF)
        p[i*2+1] = itoh(buf[i] & 0xF)
    }

    return NSString(bytesNoCopy: p, length: count*2, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue, freeWhenDone: true)! as String
 }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `var hexString : String { return self.map { String(format:"%02x", $0) }.joined() }` ?

Comment: This String is used for various patterns so

Comment: Any feedback on the answer?

Comment: Thanks your answer worked.

Comment: If an answer helped then you can *accept* it by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3 you have to use [`withUnsafeBytes()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780450-withunsafebytes) to access the raw bytes of a `Data` value. In your case:

```
withUnsafeBytes { (buf: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
    for i in 0..<count {
        p[i*2] = itoh((buf[i] >> 4) & 0xF)
        p[i*2+1] = itoh(buf[i] & 0xF)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use the fact that `Data` is a collection of bytes:

```
for (i, byte) in self.enumerated() {
    p[i*2] = itoh((byte >> 4) & 0xF)
    p[i*2+1] = itoh(byte & 0xF)
}
```

Note that there is another problem in your code:

```
NSString(..., freeWhenDone: true)
```

uses `free()` to release the memory, which means that it must be
allocated with `malloc()`.

Other (shorter, but potentially less efficient) methods to create 
a hex representation of a `Data` value can be found at 
[How to convert Data to hex string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift).