# Contextual type 'String' cannot be used with array literal

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting an error while converting my code to Swift 3.0. My sample code is below:

```
func hexRepresentation()->String {

    let dataLength:Int = self.count
    let string = NSMutableString(capacity: dataLength*2)
    let dataBytes:UnsafeRawPointer = (self as NSData).bytes

    for idx in 0..<dataLength {
         string.appendFormat("%02x", [UInt(dataBytes[idx])] as String )
    }

    return string as String
}
```

Comment: Compare [How to convert Data to hex string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift) for simpler methods to create hex encoded string representation of a Data value.

Comment: Also, for those times when you actually do need to access a `Data` object's byte pointer (which isn't this case, but still), it's much preferable to use `.withUnsafeBytes()` rather than casting to `NSData` and using its `.bytes`, to avoid the superhappyfuntimes that can result if the `Data`'s storage gets reaped sooner than you think it will.

Comment: ... which is what I suggested in response to his/her previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/46169483/1187415 :)

Answer (score 0):

What does this line do:

```
 string.appendFormat("%02x", [UInt(dataBytes[idx])] as String )
```

First of all, it takes the byte at index `idx` in `dataBytes` and wraps it in an array. This is the array literal referred to in the error message.

Next it tries to cast the array as a `String` - not convert: cast. This the compiler knows to be impossible, hence the error message.

Fortunately, you don't want to convert the argument to a string because your format specifier asks for a `UInt` (`%x`), so what you really want here is just

```
string.appendFormat("%02x", UInt(dataBytes[idx]))
```

As for getting the bytes, the Swift type `Data` has a function [foreach](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780184-foreach) which is handy for iterating the bytes:

```
self.forEach { string.appendFormat("%02x", UInt($0)) }
```

Comment: Self is Extension of Data

Comment: If is use this "string.appendFormat("%02x", UInt(dataBytes[idx]))" there is an error which says "Type UnsafeRawPointer has no subscript members"

Comment: @SIlyas So, if it is an extension of `Data` just use `forEach`

Comment: Thanks, I will use this.