# swift gzip data to string issue

Tags: ios, swift, string, gzip, nsdata

I use gzip library to convert `data` to `gzip data`

If I want to get string from data I do `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` . But if I do the same for `gzip data` I get `nil` string, because as far as I understand it's impossible to convert gzip data to string with .utf8 encoding.

I need that because I want to compare data with a server developer (because he sometimes he says that my data is incorrect format, but sometimes it's ok, and that's strange because I use the same library, and I have thoughts that may be the problem is on server side).

**Is there any way to convert gzip data to any string to compare it then later?**

Comment: `String:(describing:(myGZipData as NSData))`? or base64 encoding? Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift ?

Comment: @Larme , thank you, could you right the answer? I'll upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is just for debug purpose, then I think the quickest way is:

```
let myGZipNSData = myGZipData as! NSData //I wrote a "!" just for the sample)
print("myGZipNSData: \(myGZipNSData)")
```

It should output:

```
myGZipNSData: <5b226d79 41727261 7956616c 75653022 2c226d79 41727261 7956616c 75653122 5d>
```

This relies on `-description` method of `NSData` which print "`<hexValue>`".
Do not rely on it on release version, almost never rely on `-description` (yes, Apple could change the behavior of `-description` in next release. It happened on a different class).

Other way (safer) to get almost the same result, you can check this question: [How to convert Data to hex string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift) which you get you the same result (almost, less space, and no `<`/`>`) as the previous one.

Other way: Base 64
Use `base64EncodedString()` method of `Data`:

```
let base64Str = myGZipData?.base64EncodedString()
print("base64Str: \(base64Str!)")
```

Output:

```
base64Str: WyJteUFycmF5VmFsdWUwIiwibXlBcnJheVZhbHVlMSJd
```

Now, there should be other way:
Have a array representation with Int values (between 0/255 instead of hex), but it seems to be for debug purpose so check if you can "reproduce the current solutions" (working/fast implementation) I gave you, and check with the server developer what he/she can do on his/her side too to compare.

Note:
For the purpose of this sample, `myGZipData` is constructed this way:

```
let array = ["myArrayValue0", "myArrayValue1"]

let myGZipData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options:[])
```

It's not really a GZipData, but the goal was to quickly have a `Data` object "big enough".