# Urlencode cyrillic characters in Swift

Tags: swift, string, urlencode, url-encoding, cyrillic

I need to convert a cyrillic string to its urlencoded version using Windows-1251 encoding. For the following example string:

> Моцарт

The correct result should be:

> %CC%EE%F6%E0%F0%F2

I tried [`addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-addingpercentencoding) but it doesn't work.

How to achieve the desired result in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSString` has a [`addingPercentEscapes(using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1415058-addingpercentescapes) method which allows to specify an arbitrary
encoding:

```
let text = "Моцарт"
if let encoded = (text as NSString).addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.windowsCP1251.rawValue) {
    print(encoded)
    // %CC%EE%F6%E0%F0%F2
}
```

*However,* this is *deprecated* as of iOS 9/macOS 10.11. It causes compiler warnings and may not be available in newer OS versions.

What you can do instead is to convert the string do `Data` with
the desired encoding,
and then convert each byte to the corresponding  `%NN` sequence (using the approach from 
[How to convert Data to hex string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift/40089462#40089462)):

```
let text = "Моцарт"
if let data = text.data(using: .windowsCP1251) {
    let encoded = data.map { String(format: "%%%02hhX", $0) }.joined()
    print(encoded)
    // %CC%EE%F6%E0%F0%F2
}
```