# download Image and save it json using SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I have json in below format which I am fetching from server and parsing using SwiftyJSON.

```
{
name: "Ganesh"
imageURL:"www.abc.com/image.png"
}
```

I am downloading image using below code :

```
do{
     let myData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
}catch{
     Print("error")
}
```

Note: "url" contains url from json which is converted from string to URL

I want to save this "myData" in same json above with different key and access the same in future.

I am trying to save myData in json using SwiftyJSON method :

```
responseJSON["image"] = try JSON(data: myData)
```

Error which I am receiving :
*"if Error while converting data into json The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."*

I am not getting what is the problem?
Image is present at that url. if I convert myData into UIImage and If I assign it on UIImageView I can see it.

Comment: I guess that `JSON(data:)` awaits for a `Data` object representing JSON Stringified. Which is not your case. I guess you want to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift ? Also, `Data(contentsOf:)` is sync, in main thread that will block your UI, use `URLSession`, or a third library: SDWebImage, KingFisher, erc.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save an image in JSON, the best way would be to convert `Data` to Base64 string

```
if let base64encodedString =  myData.base64EncodedString(){
    responseJSON["image"] = base64encodedString
}
```

To restore image, try this

```
guard let base64encodedString = responseJSON["image"] as? String else { return }
guard let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: base64encodedString) else { return }
let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

Although Base64 - encoded images take approximately 33% more space than raw data, they are web and database safe - base64 strings contain neither control characters, nor quotes, and can be transferred as parameter in URL query strings.