# What is equivalent of java ByteBuffer in Swift or Objective C?

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, swift

I need to create some random data in the same way in java. Like this following snippet.

`ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
 bb.putDouble(0, Math.random());
 bb.putDouble(8, Math.random());
 String input = Hex.encodeHexString(bb.array());`

How to do same way in iOS (Swift or Objective-C) and What is the equivalent of ByteBuffer in iOS ?

Comment: It is array of bytes: `[UInt8]`

Comment: @Cy-4AH I have seen same in other docs but how we will create random byte array.

Comment: @KarthikMandava: If your actual problem is to create a random array of bytes then please update the question (and title) accordingly. That can be done in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the object you are looking for is `Data`. It is an object that can represent any data and holds raw byte buffer.

For your specific case you need to convert array of double values to data which can be done like this:

```
let data: Data = doubleArray.withUnsafeBufferPointer { Data(buffer: $0) }
```

Now to get the hex string from `Data` I suggest you reference [some other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40089462/526828).

Adding this answer code you should be able to construct your hex string by doing

```
let hexString = data.hexEncodedString()
```

So to put it ALL together you would do:

```
extension Data {
    struct HexEncodingOptions: OptionSet {
        let rawValue: Int
        static let upperCase = HexEncodingOptions(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    }

    func hexEncodedString(options: HexEncodingOptions = []) -> String {
        let format = options.contains(.upperCase) ? "%02hhX" : "%02hhx"
        return map { String(format: format, $0) }.joined()
    }
}

func generateRandomDoubleBufferHexString(count: Int, randomParameters: (min: Double, max: Double, percision: Int) = (0.0, 1.0, 100000)) -> String {

    func generateRandomDouble(min: Double = 0.0, max: Double = 1.0, percision: Int = 100000) -> Double {
        let scale: Double = Double(Int(arc4random())%percision)/Double(percision)
        return min + (max-min)*scale
    }

    var doubleArray: [Double] = [Double]() // Create empty array
    // Fill array with random values
    for _ in 0..<count {
        doubleArray.append(generateRandomDouble(min: randomParameters.min, max: randomParameters.max, percision: randomParameters.percision))
    }

    // Convert to data:
    let data: Data = doubleArray.withUnsafeBufferPointer { Data(buffer: $0) }

    // Convert to hex string
    return data.hexEncodedString()
}
```