# How can i get Characteristic value in bluetooth peripheral in swift4?

Tags: ios, swift4, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

```
  <CBCharacteristic: 0x281bc6100, UUID = FFF1, properties = 0x10, value = <500c0b62 00008f2c 10223344 55660000 00000000>, notifying = NO>
```

i want this value  " <500c0b62 00008f2c 10223344 55660000 00000000>"

can any one help me ?

Comment: `let value = myCharacteristic.value`. Now, what's supposed to be " <500c0b62 00008f2c 10223344 55660000 00000000>"? What is it supposed to mean? Is that a "text"? A custom struct you send? We can't guess how to parse it without infos of the specs of your peripheral.

Comment: i want to  print  this value  <500c0b62 00008f2c 10223344 55660000 00000000> from  peripheral.how can i get this value ?.

Comment: `let value = myCharacteristic.value`. But `<500c0b62 00008f2c 10223344 55660000 00000000>` is more a debug value, you can get it with `print("\(value as NSData)")`, but printing hex data seems weird. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift for the hex representation.

Comment: thanks...you so much i got value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if(characteristic.value != nil){
            if let ASCIIstring = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                characteristicASCIIValue = ASCIIstring
                print("Value Recieved: \((characteristicASCIIValue as String))")

            }
        }
```

Comment: Please don't do `if(characteristic.value != nil)` and then `characteristic.value!`: instead, directly safely unwrap with "if let", it's much better and swifty.