# Swift could not cast value of NSDictionaryM to NSData

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

```
Output:    
({
    "Client Characteristic Configuration" = <41424344 45463132 31323334 35363738 45324441>;
})

Code : 
print("localName4", localName4)

if (localName4 != nil) {
    print("exists")

    if localName4 is Dictionary<AnyHashable,Any> {
        print("Yes, it's a Dictionary")

        do {
            if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: localName4 as! Data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                print(jsonResult)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying get value `<41424344 45463132 31323334 35363738 45324441>` from result. When I try to parse the value getting exception:

> Could not cast value of type 'NSDictionaryM' to 'NSData'

Comment: What are you trying to archive? `localName4` is a dictionary already and you're  trying to cast the dict to `Data` and then through JSONSerialization back to a Dictionary?

Comment: i am trying get <41424344 45463132 31323334 35363738 45324441> value

Comment: What's "Output" exactly? From which print is it from?

Comment: func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber){

  let localName4 = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey]
}

Comment: `localName4` is a `(NS)Data` object, not a `(NS)Dictionary`. That's expected behaviour (It's in the doc of `CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey`). I don't understand what you want (why JSON?)? Your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift with `localName4` which is a `Data` object.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to cast it to `Data` and serialize it back to a `Dictionary`. To access values from dictionaries just call them by the key:

```
let configuration = localName4["Client Characteristic Configuration"]
```

If the declaration type of `localName4` is not `[AnyHashable : Any]` change the declaration if possible or cast it like this:

```
if let dict = localName4 as? [AnyHashable : Any] {
    let configuration = dict["Client Characteristic Configuration"]
    ...
}
```

Comment: i am getting nil value  when i print configuration

Comment: configuration [AnyHashable(Client Characteristic Configuration): <41424344 45463132 31323334 35363738 45324441>] got this value while i print dict

Comment: Can you replace `AnyHashable` with `String`?

Comment: if condition success block not getting called

Comment: Ok, now you need to find out what type the key is. Because it's not a String. Print the result of `type(of: localName4)` or even iterate through the keys with `Array(localName4.keys).forEach({ print("\(type(of: $0))") })`

Comment: sorry i could not  understand.Please give detail code