# Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer' to expected argument type 'RawPointer' in Swift5

Tags: ios, swift, device

I'm trying to get a device token.

1. First of all, is this unique value?

   I recognize it as a unique value and try to get it.  And I was following the way to get a device token when I saw an error.

```swift
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let chars = UnsafePointer<CChar>((deviceToken as NSData).bytes)  // get Error 
        var token = ""
        
        for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
            token += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [chars[i]])
        }
        
        print("Registration succeeded!")
        print("Token: ", token)
    }
```

> Error is Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer' to expected
> argument type 'RawPointer'

How can I remove this error?

And

2. is this a value that won't change if you reinstall the app?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Swift 3 you can convert `Data` to a hex string much simpler

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {  
    let token = deviceToken.map{ String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
    print("Registration succeeded!")
    print("Token: ", token)
}
```

Your questions:

1. Yes
2. The value changes periodically. If you don't manage a server which sends push notifications you don't need to care about the token.

Comment: Thank you, but is this a value that doesn't change when user reinstall the app?

Comment: Thank you for your revised reply. I'd like to ask you one more question. So, if I want to get a value that doesn't change when user reinstall the app, how do I get it?

Comment: Basically the value doesn't change when you reinstall the app but you have no control over the token. The APN Server can send a new token at any time.