# How to access the code of a HashedAuthenticationCode (as a String)?

Tags: swift, ios13, apple-cryptokit

Given the following `HashedAuthenticationCode`:

```swift
import CryptoKit
let key = SymmetricKey(size: .bits256)
let message = "Hello world!".data(using: .utf8)!
let authenticationCode = HMAC<SHA256>.authenticationCode(for: message, using: key)
print(authenticationCode) // "HMAC with SHA256: c818a1400a9995d5faafbb5d41cc88a6701b5d1a4ded8ac169498319a2597e2a"
```

How do I access the `c818a1400a9995d5faafbb5d41cc88a6701b5d1a4ded8ac169498319a2597e2a` value? Utimately this must be encoded and serialized over a `URLSession`, but I see no obvious property for getting the "code" part of the HAC!

Comment: The string you're describing is a hex-encoding of a sequence of bytes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift  The only difference is that this is a MessageAuthenticationCode rather than a Data, but the approach is identical. You format each byte as a hex value.