# Convert Swift struct to Data bytes

Tags: ios, c, swift, struct, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to pass bytes data to bluetooth service in a format that is expected by bluetooth firmware.

Expected data structure in c struct are:

```
typedef enum {
        CMD_TX_INFO = 0,
        CMD_DATA_REQ_START,
        CMD_DATA_REQ_END,
        CMD_DATA_REQ
} ble_cmd_type_t;

typedef struct ble_data_info_s
{
        uint32_t data_size_bytes;
        uint32_t info;
} ble_data_info_t;

typedef PACKED ( struct ble_cmd_info
{
        ble_cmd_type_t  cmd_type;
        ble_data_info_t info;
        uint8_t len;
        uint8_t data[10];
}) ble_cmd_data_t;
```

I have converted the this to swift struct as follows:

```
enum BLECmdType : UInt8{
    case CMD_TX_INFO = 0
    case CMD_DATA_REQ_START
    case CMD_DATA_REQ_END
    case CMD_DATA_REQ
}

struct BLEDataInfo
{
    let dataSizeBytes: UInt32
    let info: UInt32
}

struct BLECmdData
{
    let cmdType:BLECmdType 
    let info:BLEDataInfo
    let len:UInt8
    let data: Array<UInt8>?
}
```

Then i convert the swit struct object into bytes like this, i am not sure if this approach is correct? I am not getting the bytes in correct expected format:

```
var command = BLECmdData(cmdType:BLECmdType.CMD_DATA_REQ_START, 
    info: BLEDataInfo(dataSizeBytes: 100000, info: 10), 
    len: 1, 
    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

let bleData = Data(bytes: &command , count: MemoryLayout<BLECmdData>.stride)
```

Firstly is it possible to print the bytes generated for **bleData** object in string format so i can debug and see?

Secondly the bytes sent to BLE device are:

```
Bytes:
01 00 00 00 A0 86 01 00
E5 73 E0 98 0A 00 00 00
70 C5 CA 80
```

Firmware engineer mentioned, data should start with following:

```
Bytes:
01 00 A0 86 01 00
E5 73 E0 98
```

I am not sure if my approach to convert c struct to swift here is correct.

Looking forward for your reply.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift

Comment: you have to know about endianness, alignment, padding ... Let me explain in the answer

Comment: I know of no way to automatically convert a Swift struct to bytes in a way that will be compatible with a C struct. You have to manually enumerate the struct's fields and covert each one individually to bytes in the desired format

Comment: I would have kept the C struct. The "match" between Swift Struct & C Struct isn't certain to be the same, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to successfully push the data in correct format:

Set the values:

```
var cmdTypeCopy:UInt8 = BLECmdType.CMD_DATA_REQ_START
var imageInfo = BLEDataInfo(dataSizeBytes: 100000, info: 10)
var cmdLenCopy = 10
var cmdDataCopy:Array<UInt8> = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Create Data:

```
var cmdTypeData = Data(bytes: &cmdTypeCopy, count: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.stride)
var imageInfoData = Data(bytes: &imageInfo, count: MemoryLayout<BLEImageInfo>.stride)
var cmdLenData = Data(bytes: &cmdLenCopy, count: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.stride)
var cmdDataData = Data(bytes: &cmdDataCopy, count: 10)
```

Then append one by one:

```
cmdTypeData.append(imageInfoData)
cmdTypeData.append(cmdLenData)
cmdTypeData.append(cmdDataData)
```

This worked perfectly and firmware got the data in correct format.

Answer (score 1):

1. the result of the line
   `let bleData = Data(bytes: &command , count: MemoryLayout<BLECmdData>.stride)`

it depends on what cpu architecture the programming you're running on. (32bits vs 64 bits, big-endian vs little-endian).

2. you have to ask `Firmware engineer` about the protocol to communicate with their devices, then you will encode the data as the format specified in the protocol. It isn't important that you store the data in a class/struct/enum etc..., the important thing is how the data is encoded.

Comment: Or at least you can ask them to provide some PACKED and the corresponding encoded data.