# Getting ResponseSerializationFailureReason Error in Alamofire API response in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, alamofire, jsonserializer

I am trying to fetch response using API but i am getting below error. Sometimes the API work and sometime it gave me this error. The API works fine in the Postman.

```
failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0}))))))
```

My Code:

```
class TemplateObserver: ObservableObject {
@Published var category = [Category]()

init(){
    fetchCategories()
}
func fetchCategories() {
    let request = AF.request(Constants.CATEGORIES, method: .get)
    request.responseDecodable(of: [Category].self) { response in
        print("Category Response: (response)")
        guard let result = response.value else { return }
        self.category = result
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to create object in the app.Swift file:

```
@main
struct Logo_MakerApp: App {
    @ObservedObject var templateObserver = TemplateObserver()

    var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView(
            templateObserver: templateObserver
        )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post  what is `Category` and `Json `?

Comment: Could your print: `print("Data stringified: \(String(data: response.data ?? Date(), encoding: .utf8))")` and show us the output?

Comment: Since it's "somtimes", and I guess the URL doesn't change, I'd guess you have a rate limit per minutes/seconds, explaining the error, or server issue. It wouldn't suprise me to see "HTML" code errors...

Comment: Model:
struct Category: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let thumbnail: String
    let color: String
}
JSON Response: 
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Architecture",
        "color": "#000000",
        "thumbnail": "http://logomaker.one/public/files/upload/logo-files/categories/logo_cat_NAFaCi_Icon.jpg",
        "is_active": 1,
        "is_delete": 0,
        "created_at": "2021-12-30T02:49:49.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-12-30T02:49:49.000000Z"
    }
]

Comment: @Larme I printed the response. [You can check from](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W3APsaE6Wv0fIk0Mh6SH-G9ZYefbBA8CMxPrxLFckSs/edit?usp=sharing). I don't think it is from server side issue. I tried to send unlimited request using postman. It is not showing error in the postman.

Comment: Is that the print when it failed? There is no content on the given link.

Comment: I suggest you add a `debugPrint(response)` to your response handler to see what the response is actually receiving.

Comment: I am getting this error "JSON could not be serialized because of error:\nThe data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format" but the app shows this error second time. First time the data load successful.

Comment: When it fails, print the content of the response then? Maybe as hex data: `response.data` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift