# Swift AFError , debugDescription : "The given data was not valid JSON."

Tags: ios, swift, rest, alamofire

When i decode my result y got this error ResponseSerializationFailureReason, this happens in calls with accents, if i have not accent decode good.

I want to decode the service result

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far. Also an example of the problematic JSON and one of an unproblamatic would be useful.

Comment: It'd be nice to share the JSON, or raw data (into hex string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift) so we can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your description, whatever is generating the JSON is not using UTF-8. It's probably using Latin-1, or possibly one of the Windows code pages (but I'm betting Latin-1).