# Specific HTTP imageURL Not Showing

Tags: swift, http

Has anyone seen a phenomenon where a specific HTTP image URL address cannot be downloaded even though the HTTP address is allowed?

HTTP image addresses of other addresses are displayed well, but there are addresses that do not work.

Here is My code and image URL - http://alivenews.net/data/file/tr_commerce/2303/20230309080756-6546.jpg

```
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
        guard
               let data = data,
               let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
               error == nil
           else {
               print("network error:", error ?? "Unknown error")
               return
           }

        guard 200 != response.statusCode else {
            print("invalid status code, expected 2xx, received", response.statusCode)
                return
        }

           guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
               print("Not valid image")
               return
           }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.newsThumailView.image = image
        }
    }.resume()
```

Returns nil value in the process of converting data to Image. What could be the problem?

Comment: when I add
 `print("---> \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")` just after the first `guard`,
 I get an html that says: "You don\'t have permission to access this resource."

Comment: It’s an http address and not https, so maybe that’s got something to do with it.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you indeed allowing NSAllowsArbitraryLoads  in info.plist?

Comment: as for me in my tests, yes.

Comment: Could you show the output of `print(response)`? Also, the first values of data? Can be done there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the test code I used and the output I get:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let urlString = "http://alivenews.net/data/file/tr_commerce/2303/20230309080756-6546.jpg"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("testing")
            .onAppear {
                getData()
            }
    }
    
    func getData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("---> bad url")
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let data = data,
                let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                error == nil
            else {
                print("network error:", error ?? "Unknown error")
                return
            }
            
            print("\n---> data: \n \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject)")
            
            print("\n---> response: \n \(response)")
            
            guard 200 != response.statusCode else {
                print("invalid status code, expected 2xx, received", response.statusCode)
                return
            }
            
            guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                print("\n--> Not valid image")
                return
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
}
```

The Info.plist

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
 <plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
     <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
     <dict>
         <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
         <true/>
     </dict>
 </dict>
 </plist>
```

The output prints:

```
 ---> data:
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
 <html><head>
 <title>403 Forbidden</title>
 </head><body>
 <h1>Forbidden</h1>
 <p>You don't have permission to access this resource.</p>
 </body></html>


 ---> response:
  <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600003ac66c0> { URL: http://alivenews.net/data/file/tr_commerce/2303/20230309080756-6546.jpg } { Status Code: 403, Headers {
     Connection =     (
         "Keep-Alive"
     );
     "Content-Length" =     (
         199
     );
     "Content-Type" =     (
         "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
     );
     Date =     (
         "Fri, 10 Mar 2023 10:31:33 GMT"
     );
     "Keep-Alive" =     (
         "timeout=5, max=256"
     );
     Server =     (
         "Apache/2.4.43 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.3.29"
     );
 } }

 --> Not valid image
```

EDIT-1:

works for me with the following `User-Agent` in the request, as mentioned in the comments. Not sure what is the most appropriate `User-Agent` to use:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let urlString = "http://alivenews.net/data/file/tr_commerce/2303/20230309080756-6546.jpg"
    
    @State var image = UIImage()
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: image)
            .onAppear {
                getData()
            }
    }
    
    func getData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("---> bad url")
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("image/png", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("Mickey Mouse", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard
            let data = data,
            let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            error == nil
        else {
            print("network error:", error ?? "Unknown error")
            return
        }
        
        guard 200 < response.statusCode || 299 > response.statusCode else {
            print("invalid status code, expected 2xx, received", response.statusCode)
            return
        }
            if let img = UIImage(data: data) {
                self.image = img
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
}
```

Note, do not use `guard 200 != response.statusCode ...`, try something like this: `guard 200 < response.statusCode || 299 > response.statusCode ...`

Comment: Also, if you switch to https, I'm seeing certificate failures, which suggests a misconfigured server.

Comment: strange that (http) works in the browser, eg Safari.

Comment: And curl. Maybe it's checking user agent

Comment: It is indeed. After checking what send my Safari.app to work, I tested all the header combinaisons, and it seems that "User-Agent" is required to work

Comment: Updated my answer with the `User-Agent`. That works for me, but not sure if it is the appropriate agent to use.