# In Alamofire.UploadRequest, how to log httpBody of wrapped URLRequest?

Tags: alamofire

The answer to this seemingly simple question is eluding me.

I am using Alamofire version 5.6.1.

I am trying to extract `httpBody` of Foundation's `URLRequest` and put it into an `NSLog` statement. However, the `URLRequest` is generated and wrapped by an `Alamofire.UploadRequest`.

`Alamofire.UploadRequest` seems to delay creation of the `URLRequest` until deep in the bowels of Alamofire. Currently, I have breakpoints in `Alamofire.Session.performUploadRequest` and the `URLRequest` still has not been fully assembled.

I tried logging from our app's data fetcher where the response comes back. The response type is `Alamofire.DataResponse` and that has a reference to the original `URLRequest`. However, at this point, the `URLRequest` is reported as having `httpBody` of `nil` and this is simply false because the call is succeeding and the data used to configure the `Alamofire.UploadRequest` which must eventually become the `httpBody` of a `URLRequest`, is arriving successfully at the backend service.

Regarding how far I have gotten, as I wrote, I can see the data still separate from a `URLRequest` contained within a `Alamofire.UploadRequest` at `Alamofire.Session.performUploadRequest`. Here is the code for that:

```
func performUploadRequest(_ request: UploadRequest) {
        dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(requestQueue))
        performSetupOperations(for: request, convertible: request.convertible) {
            do {
                let uploadable = try request.upload.createUploadable()
                // START of code I added.
                switch uploadable {
                case .data(let d):
                    let s = String(data: d, encoding: .utf8)
                    NSLog("YOJEFF uploadable case data = \(String(describing: s))")
                default:
                    NSLog("YOJEFF uploadable case is not data")
                }
                // END of code I added.
                self.rootQueue.async { request.didCreateUploadable(uploadable) }
```

And that shows the data which will eventually become `httpBody` of a `URLRequest` but I want to log the data from the **actual** `URLRequest` passed to a `URLSession`.

How much deeper into Alamofire must I go? Or am I missing some property further up?

I already have a logger that I wrote that conform to `Alamofire.EventMonitor`, and it is injected into `Alamofire.Session` but why that is not working on this particular network call is a separate puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URLSessionUploadTask`s, which Alamofire uses under the upload functionality, don't use the `httpBody` property. Instead, it attaches to the `httpBodyStream` of the `URLRequest` after it's passed into the `URLSession` issuing the request. Currently Alamofire doesn't have any events that occur when this happens (`URLSession` is generally a blackbox at that level) but you can access `request.task.currentRequest` to get the current state of the `URLRequest` as `URLSession` operates. In fact, this value is key value observable, so you could even get a live observation from that:

```swift
session.upload(...)
  .onURLSessionTaskCreation { task in
    <store observation> = task.observe(\.currentRequest) { task, change in
      debugPrint(task.currentRequest?.httpBodyStream)
    }
  }
```

In my testing this value actually changes a few times under `URLSession`, which is one of the reasons Alamofire offers no built-in hooks here.

However, it may be simpler to log your upload before it's passed to the request in the first place, especially if all you're trying to do is confirm its value. You could do this before creating the upload at all or by implementing the `request(_ request:didCreateUploadable:)` event.

Answer (score 0):

I am still going deeper and deeper into the bowels of Alamofire to get its code where `Alamofire.UploadRequest` attaches it data to its `URLRequest.httpBody` and I have no found it yet, but as a stopgap in *Xcode*, selection "Product > Profile" from the menu bar and when *Instruments* launches, choosing "Network" template will allow you to sniff the HTTP traffic from your app. There are a few points:

- Instruments only works on real devices not Simulators.
- The non DEBUG build (Production configuration) of your app will be run
- You cannot text scrape (copy) the HTTP request/response. You'll have to screenshot to share the info.

Comment: Other network proxy tools like Charles or Proxyman will also work if you need to inspect what's going out. Wireshark can also be used for low level network inspection.